water leak through subfloor underneath toilet
I have a leak in the bathroom underneath another bathroom and from what I can gather, this water spot (2 inch in diameter) appeared today and is coming from a toilet in the room above.
Around that toilet, everything is dry. I installed that toilet a couple of years ago and I did not caulk around the edge. There is also no odor around it (so far).
The spot on the ceiling is approx. at the 'front' of the toilet. The water connection (coming to the toilet) comes from the wall behind the toilet.
Any idea what this could be? And if it would be an easy fix?

Water spills running under the toilet, or wax ring leaking.  Just because it is dry now, does not mean it was dry a few days ago.

This sounds like a common toilet to flange seal leak.
To be certain you must pull the toilet and take a look.  If you prefer not to do that, close the bath door and place a "DO NOT USE" sign on the door.  If after a few days of no one flushing the toilet, the spot drys you then know it's the toilet seal.  In reality it isn't difficult to pull the toilet and replace the seal. However look for a cracked flange while you are there.  A flange repair ring will take care of that.

Appreciate the response! So, would I need to replace the flange+wax ring, or just the wax ring? I did notice that the bolts on the sides of the toilet weren't tight at all and the bowl is able to move a little because of that (turn, etc.).

You need to examine the flange for cracks. Often the seal does not fail unless the flange fails and the bolts do not hold well.  Take a close look at the flange.

Much appreciated! Took the toilet off, cleaned all the wax off the spot and inspected the flange. The flange looked good: no cracks there. Installed a new wax ring (the reinforced one with horn, to be on the safe side). No leaking for the past few weeks!
